# Why is this dangling-gsl warning invoked?

Tags: c++, pointers, warnings, clang-tidy, cpp-core-guidelines

I am analyzing a codebase with clang-tidy and see a warning I do not understand. The warning is invoked by the following lines of code:

```cpp
void fun(const QString& bar) {
    const char* c_format = bar.toStdString().c_str();
    expand_some_macro(c_format);
}
```

`c_format` is passed around in the expanded macro which reads as follows:

```cpp
#define expand_some_macro(c_format)\
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE];\
    va_list args;\
    va_start(args, c_format);\
    vsnprintf(buffer, MAX_SIZE, _TRUNCATE, c_format, args);\
    va_end(args);
```

which includes function calls from the [`shlobj`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj/) header that I do not  understand at this point. The `clang-tidy` generates the following warning:

```sh
warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [clang-diagnostic-dangling-gsl]
```

I browsed the web, in particular the [c++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines), in an attempt to educate myself about this warning but could not find a proper reference. This lead me to two sets of questions:

1. What is a reference for this warning?  Where can I learn about this an similar warnings?
2. What might be wrong with the code above? Do I need to call `delete[] c_format` at the end of the scope?

Comment: G.M answered my question but just to leave some reference to illustrate the broader point of not pointing to temporaries (and because I do not know the etiquette for editing questions:
1. [GCC's warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Temporaries.html) and 2. the [Core Guideline](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es84-dont-try-to-declare-a-local-variable-with-no-name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the statement...

```
const char* c_format = bar.toStdString().c_str();
```

`bar.toStdString()` returns a temporary `std::string` which will be destroyed *before* the next statement.  But you then call `std::string::c_str()` against that temporary variable and save its return value to be used in...

```
expand_some_macro(c_format);
```

So, by the time `c_format` is used in the above expression the memory it points to has already been released when the temporary `std::string` was destroyed.  Hence the warning.

However, without knowing what your macro does (or why it needs to be a macro) it's difficult to say much more.

**Edit:**

By way of clarification, the code you have currently could be rewritten (more or less) as...

```
const char* c_format = nullptr;
{
    std::string str = bar.toStdString();
    c_format = str.c_str();
}
expand_some_macro(c_format);
```

So you're using the memory pointed to by `c_format` beyond its lifetime.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful answer! I do understand that `bar.toStdString()` create a temporary variable, but I do not fully understand why this is a problem. Does that mean by the end of the line, `c_fomat` is already a dangling pointer? I have also updated the question to reflect your statement that knowledge of the macro might be helpful.

Comment: Edited to add some clarification.